# Рендер 3D модели в Unity 5 2D игре

Tags: unity3d, model, 2d

Нужно рендерить 3D-модель в качестве спрайта в 2D-игре. Проблема в том, что рисовать спрайты мне очень даже не хочется, тем более 3D-модели на мой взгляд лучше в качестве. Имеются такие файлы как:

- *.obj
- *.mtl
- *.smd (Кстати насчёт этого хотел спросить, всё таки можно ли использовать скелетную анимацию в Unity?)
- *.png (текстуры сами по себе)

При импорте модели в качестве ассетса ничего не получалось, точнее получалось, но:

1. Слишком большой размер
2. Текстуры не накладывались каким угодно способом. Материлы для них делал.
3. Ну и собственно я не понимаю как можно сделать анимацию из smd.

Хотел бы сказать, что в геймдеве я новичок, стараюсь понять что да как, но в разработке приложений я разбираюсь (Знаю в основном Java, C#, учу C++).
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем рисовать то самома ?
Или на мобильном устройстве рендерить модель в спрайты (кстати, зачем, если она должна и так прекрасно работать), где ресурсы весьма ограничены, в частности заряд батареи и производительность ?

Загрузите модель в редактор (например, [Blender](https://www.blender.org/)) и наделайте себе спрайтов...

Comment: Блендером я и пользуюсь. Но модельки то не мои, а делать из них спрайты долго. "кстати, зачем, если она должна и так прекрасно работать" - вы имеете ввиду, что можно использовать просто модель? Хех, я так то так и хотел тогда сделать))

Comment: А как в итоге сделали?

Comment: Да никак. В итоге, спустя несколько месяцев мне дали ответ, но думаете мне он уже нужен? Нет, не то, чтобы вы зря мне его дали, спасибо, но увы, я сам уже сделал это как раз таки именно так, но, в итоге забросил по личным проблемам.